# Having issue trying to create pagination system in Yii 2 with sql data provider

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to implement a pagination system with `Yii 2` and making use of a [SQL Data Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#sql-data-provider) but I am getting the below error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

This is being caused by `line 215` in the [getOrders](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Sort.php#L208) Yii method within the `sort` class; which is caused by this bit in the code below `$models = $dataProvider->getModels();`.

Here is the generalized code:

```
$sql = $this->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table WHERE some_id=:some_id");
$sql->bindValue(':some_id', $this->some_id);
$count = $sql->queryScalar();

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_id=:some_id',
    'params' => [':some_id' => $this->some_id],
    'totalCount' => $count,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'sort_way_1' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_2' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_2' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 1',
            ],
            'sort_way_2' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_4' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_4' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 2',
            ],
            'sort_way_3' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_5' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_5' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 3',
            ],
            'sort_way_4' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_6' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_6' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 4',
            ],
        ],
        'enableMultiSort' => false,
        'defaultOrder' => [
                           'col_1' => SORT_DESC,
                           'col_2' => SORT_DESC,
                           'col_3' => SORT_DESC,
                           ],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => $this->per_page,
        'page' => $this->page,
        'pageSizeLimit' => [5,100],
        'pageSizeParam' => 'per_page',
        'totalCount' => $count,
    ],
]);

$models = $dataProvider->getModels();
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Show var_dump($columns) right after this line https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Sort.php#L214. Also you have columns in 'defaultOrder' that are not listed in sort attributes (they are 'sort_way_1' to 'sort_way_4').

Comment: I did the `var_dump` and I get `null`. Not sure what you mean about my `defaultOrder`, I want the default order to be the same as `sort_way_1 desc` - doesn't it match right?

Comment: So in that case 'defaultOrder' should be just ['sort_way_1' => SORT_DESC], you already described it explicitly in sort attributes section.

Comment: Thanks - that fixed the error. Understand it now.

Comment: OK, I issued this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `defaultOrder` declaration.

You should use only attributes declared in sort attributes section (in your case they are `sort_way_1` to `sort_way_4`).

For order by `sort_way_1` in descending direction just simply use:

```
'defaultOrder' => ['sort_way_1' => SORT_DESC],
```

And there is no need to copy all columns because your already described it explicitly here:

```
'sort_way_1' => [
    ...
    'desc' => [
        'col_1' => SORT_DESC,
        'col_2' => SORT_DESC,
        'col_3' => SORT_DESC,
    ],
    ...
],
```